# Web Optimization: Why are Combined Files Faster?

Tags: html, performance, optimization

I have read that combining all of your css files into one big one, or all of your script files into a single script file reduces the number of HTTP requests and therefore speeds up download speed.

But I don't understand this. I thought that if you had multiple files (up to a limit, which is 10 I believe on modern browsers), the browser would download them in parallel, thus REDUCING the total time to download (divided by the number of connections allowed).

I am obviously missing a key piece of info here. Can someone turn on the lights?

Comment: There is usually a strict, very low limit to parallel downloading on both the browser and the server side; also, the request itself is expensive. This is why it's usually better to have one big file

Comment: To expand on that, the limit is usually 2. Keep in mind that it may not be a good idea to combine everything into one single file. If there are scripts or CSS that are prone to frequent updates, it may be best to leave them out or combine those into a separate file. Otherwise, your visitors will have to redownload one huge file again and again.

Comment: See this for specific numbers: http://www.die.net/musings/page_load_time/ @simshaun: That used to be the case with Cthulhu, it's been bumped to 6 in IE8.

Comment: Guys, these are answers! Put 'em as answers? Or as one, edited answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's overhead in every request/response.  That's essentially what it comes down to.

Here's an example of a request header to Google ...

> GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1
>   Accept: application/x-ms-application,
>   image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml,
>   image/gif, image/pjpeg,
>   application/x-ms-xbap,
>   application/vnd.ms-excel,
>   application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,
>   application/msword,
>   application/x-shockwave-flash, */*
>   Accept-Language: en-US User-Agent:
>   Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0;
>   Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0;
>   GTB0.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727;
>   .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; OfficeLiveConnector.1.4;
>   OfficeLivePatch.1.3) Accept-Encoding:
>   gzip, deflate Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Host: www.google.com Cookie:
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I wrote an article about this last year... 
http://swortham.blogspot.com/2010/03/latency-requests-css-sprites-and-you.html

You are right that multiple files can be downloaded in parallel (2 or more from a single hostname, depending on the browser).  And that in turn will cause the page to load progressively, which is good.  But that doesn't mean that your homepage should be composed of 20+ css, js, and image files.  Ideally you'd want to combine quite a bit to optimize the site.

Answer (score 3):

Several things:

- TCP setup and teardown - with the widespread use of keep-alive and pipelining, this is no longer too significant, except with some proxies which fall back to this "one HTTP request - one TCP connection" model for compatibility reasons.
- HTTP headers overhead - this could be significant for small files - hundreds of bytes of headers can be larger than the response body.
- latency (time from request start to response start) - this is somewhat reduced with keepalive and pipelining
- limits on parallel downloads - this is the main one. IE6 used to limit this to 2 connections per hostname, it has been bumped to 6 in IE8 (other browsers have had sane limits for a while). See [this older study](http://www.die.net/musings/page_load_time/) on further parallelizing this ("use 4 domain names instead of 1").